# SQL Post Tables

Tags: sql, data-modeling, erd

Hey I am trying to set up a table where activities can be shared/posted. There are two options of shares/posts: public and private(friends). 
I hope somebody can help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You"ll need to be more specific with your question .

Are you referring to ORM or sql

From my understanding, you'll need to set up type that can be changed

e.g type: { 
        Default: 'public'
  }

Users should be able to view data or posts based on the sign in type

Comment: Hi, 
I am referring to SQL/ERD (don't know what ORM is). A friend post is only for one pair of friends (Table: Friendship)
If I include a flag (public), I would have to have a foreign key for Frienship, which can be empty. Can I do that, or is that bad practice?